# It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, virtual-directory

I want to manage two web.config file in a application one for the front-end user and second for the back-end(admin) user.for admin section I have created a folder with name **admin** in the same website.following settiongs are in the **admin/web.config**

when I am trying to run the application I am getting following error message:

**It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS**

Same problem have discussed on below 
[ASP.NET What causes: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546568/asp-net-error-tt-is-an-error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinitionmac)

[It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690909/it-is-an-error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinitionmachinetoapplicati)

Please give me some suggestion to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

I faced same issue when I had a web application inside another web application resulting in two Web.config files.I deleted one and issue was solved.
As configuration settings in the child level can override the ones in parent level,this error can occur when you have 2 web.config files one redefining configuration settings that you cannot override such as authentication or session state.  Issue happens when you may have authentication / session state set on the lower level web.config and also in higher level web.config

Comment: That did the trick for me.  I removed the "authentication" node on the nested web.config and it worked right away.  Thanks!

Comment: I had a few backup subfolders to keep a few files without changes. It seems they were creating a conflict with the main web.config file.

Answer (score 6):

- There are an enormous amount of
  information on getting this error in
  IIS. I have spent hours on issues
  like this, because, there has never
  been a CLEAR ANSWER.

  You will hear things like

  > > It means that if you have an application, you should not configure
  > >     the MachineToApplication settings in
  > >     web.config's in the subdirectories.
  >
  > All you have to do is set the
  >   MachineToApplication settings in your
  >   Application's root, and they will be
  >   inherited in the subdirectories.
  >
  > Solution :
  >
  > Configure all MachineToApplication
  >   settings in your application's root,
  >   and remove all MachineToApplication
  >   settings from your application's
  >   subdirectories.

  What all of the answers FAIL TO
  MENTION is that there are a myriad of
  file permissions, security, etc..
  going on with any file in IIS.

  It used to be easier, but with the
  increase in the proliferation, it is
  getting much, much more complicated.

  I have one solution which I have used
  which got my IIS to work-

  1st. Test a simple HTML page in a new
  Web App. If you can get that to work,
  then you should be good for the next
  steps.

  2nd. When you are thinking about the
  issue that started this, you have a
  Machine.config file in the
  E:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG
  directory for your Framework.

  This is the file that sets the Type
  of AllowedDefinitions. ( look for
  that in the config file)either
  allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"
  or allowDefinition="Machine"

  When someone says you have to put
  your web.config in your applications
  "Root" Folder, depending on how your
  application is setup, will dictate
  where to put your web.config.

  To get mine to work, I put it in the
  E:\Inetpub\wwwroot folder.

  3rd. You will have to test which
  sections to include in the config
  root folder, and which ones you can
  put in your various web "Application"
  folders.

  4th. This is a work in progress, but
  I wanted to get this out there while
  I was working on it and it was fresh
  in my mind...

  I'll post more later when I iron out
  more of the issues.

  I plan to post an extremely detailed
  explanation later on when I decipher
  all of the cryptic, purposefully
  undocumented, sometimes misleading,
  information on the matter of configs,
  etc. to get IIS running properly.

  ie. I'm tired of hacking around
  trying to get it to behave properly,
  but I want to thoroughly test the
  system out and document, EXACTLY what
  needs to be done, and why, to get
  applications up and running
  quickly...

  Thanks for reading this.

Comment: The fact that this post wasn't updated in the 10 years since its creation doesn't bode well despite this error continuing to crop up!

Answer (score 3):

You need to set it as as an application in IIS.

Comment: I am using IIS 6, how I will do this, can you tell me the steps

Comment: from the top of my head: right click the folder, open the properties and look for an option that says make application or something like that.

Comment: http://www.affiliatewiz.com/support/appstartpoint.asp (just searched: iis create application)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using a Kentico installation. Admittedly this is no silver bullet, but in this case it was because one of the base templates `CorporateSiteAspx` had its own webconfig file containing configuration settings that used `requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"`

On excluding this file (which wasn't used anyway) the application built successfully.